# Linear Regression - predicted values constantly below true values

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, python, linear

just a short question, which may be easy to solve for most of you.
I am just starting with linear regression models in python.
Therefore I made a simple multiple linear regression with training and test data.
If you have a look into the trained model, everything looks fine - but if I want to use it for my testing data the following problem occurs.

All predicted Values are constantly below the true values - what could be the reason for this issue and how to handle this?

Enclosed the code:

```
x = features_m_2007
y = target_m_2007

def split_data(data, split_date):
    return data[data.index <= split_date].copy(), \
           data[data.index >  split_date].copy()

train_x, test_x = split_data(x, '2017-01-01')
train_y, test_y = split_data(y, '2017-01-01')

Regression_model = LinearRegression()
Regression_model.fit(train_x, train_y)
pred_y = Regression_model.predict(test_x)

MIN=0
MAX=150
MAX=np.min([MAX,len(test_y)])
x_vals=np.arange(MIN,MAX)
y_pred_vals=pred_y
y_test_vals=test_y
plt.figure(figsize=(26,10))
plt.plot(x_vals,y_pred_vals,'ro--',label="predicted")
plt.plot(x_vals,y_test_vals,'bo--',label="true")
plt.xticks(x_vals, test_y.index)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you made a mistake, and without seeing the code and maybe also the data, chances are nobody here can tell you which one.

Comment: @Lewian Thanks for the hint, I attached the code